# "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" при использовании dsolve

Tags: matlab

Нужно построить график функции, однако после функции:

```
>> dsolve('U+0.15*10^(-6)*(22*10^3+0.27*10^3)*DU=0','U(0)=1')
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
>   logicals.
>
> Error in ==> dsolve at 202
>
> indx(isalphanumunder(eq_str(indx-1))|isalphanumunder(eq_str(indx-1)))
>   = [];

Answer (score 1):

Предположу: что не хватает скобок:

```
'U+0.15*(10^(-6))*(22*10^3+0.27*10^3)*DU=0'
```

Ну и еще где-то)

Comment: Нет, не поэтому